# Java average program with any number of inputs

Tags: java, average

What I'm trying to make is an averaging program that takes any number of inputs. So far I need to have the user specify how many numbers they want to average, and if they don't give that many numbers the program crashes. Is there any way that I could just have them put as many numbers as they want and afterwards the array length is set?

Here is the code I am using right now:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Average_any
{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println ("How many numbers do you want to enter?");

        final int ARRAY_LENGTH = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println ("Please type the numbers you want to find the average of, "
                            + "and then type \"Done\".");
        System.out.println ("Warning: Only type the exact amount of numbers that you specified.");
        // If user doesn't enter same number, results in crash
        double[] numbers = new double [ARRAY_LENGTH];
        do {
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.println("That's not a number!");
                scan.next(); //Need this to enter another input
                }
                numbers[i] = scan.nextInt();
            }
        } while (!scan.hasNext("Done"));

        double total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            total += numbers[i];
        }

        double average = total/ARRAY_LENGTH;

        System.out.println ("Your average is: " + average);
    }
}
```

(Just in case anyone is wondering, no this is not a school assignment, I was just wondering because we did a simpler version in school)

Comment: Have you heard of a `List`?

Comment: No, sorry I'm a little new to coding besides HTML and CSS

Comment: (That was a slightly rhetorical question.  I was really suggesting you do some research into lists.)

Comment: take a look at `java.util.List`, `java.util.ArrayList` and `java.util.LinkedList`. you should nearly always use them instead of native arrays. you will find lots of tutorials about how to use them. they are the solution here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the array out of the equation altogether

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
double total = 0;
int count = 0;

while (scan.hasNextDouble()) {
    total += scan.nextDouble();
    count ++;
}
double average = total / count;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a lot quicker than using arrays or lists